# IE 8 Proxy exceptions list

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I want to update  automatically proxy exceptions list  in the IE 8 using a REG  or  VBS.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered WPAD?

Comment: First of all, thanks your suggestion.But ,I want to do it now.So , I want to update automatically proxy only exceptions list in the IE 8 using a REG or VBS. Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a very odd route for tweaking the proxy config - why don't you use the [standard method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) designed for the purpose?